# using \def in \newcommand

Tags: macros

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\def\startnewpart{FALSE}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi                                                                                                                                       
%                    \def\startnewpart{FALSE} 
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%                                                                                                                                                                  
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
%                    \def\startnewpart{FALSE}                                                                                                                                                               
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Methods}
Some text
\end{document}
```

If in `\renewcommand\chapter` I uncomment the first  `\def\startnewpart{FALSE}` the document compiles fine.

If instead I uncomment the second `\def\startnewpart{FALSE}` I get an error:

```
Chapter 1.
! Missing { inserted.
\@makechapterhead ...1\par \nobreak \vskip 40\p@ }

l.21 \tableofcontents
```

Where is the difference?

In this example I am exploring how to use a control variable `\startnewpart` to control the execution of `\chapter`. `\def\startnewpart{FALSE}` is meant to reset the value of `\startnewpart`.

Comment: `\@chapter` and `\@schapter` look ahead to collect arguments, so they have to be last in the definition.

Comment: @HenriMenke, is that the purpuse of using `@`?

Comment: No.  `@` just emphasizes that this is not a user command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\secdef` is defined as

```
% latex.ltx, line 6086:
\def\secdef#1#2{\@ifstar{#2}{\@dblarg{#1}}}
```

In your case you get

```
\@ifstar{\@schapter}{\@dblarg{\@chapter}}
```

Now `\@ifstar` looks at the following token. If you uncomment the second `\def` line, the next token is not a `*`, but `\def`. Thus LaTeX finds

```
\@dblarg{\@chapter}\def\startnewpart{FALSE}
```

Here's the definition of `\@dblarg`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1105:
\long\def\@dblarg#1{\kernel@ifnextchar[{#1}{\@xdblarg{#1}}}
```

Thus you get

```
\kernel@ifnextchar[{\@chapter}{\@xdblarg{\@chapter}}\def\startnewpart{FALSE}
```

The macro `\kernel@ifnextchar` absorbs three arguments, here `[`, `{\@chapter}` and `{\@xdblarg{\@chapter}}` and checks whether the next token is `[`. It isn't, because it's `\def`, so the effect is to get

```
\@xdblarg{\@chapter}\def\startnewpart{FALSE}
```

OK, let's look at `\@xdblarg`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1106:
\long\def\@xdblarg#1#2{#1[{#2}]{#2}}
```

Here `#1` is `{\@chapter}` (but the braces will be removed by rule), so you end up with

```
\@chapter[{\def}]{\def}\startnewpart{FALSE}
```

which is surely not something you'd like to have in your code.

It's not really tied to `\def`. Commands such as

```
\secdef\A\B
\@ifstar{A}{B}
\@ifnextchar<char>{A}{B}
```

should ***always*** come last in a definition code, because they want to look at what comes next.